# How can I use part of a larger image as a marker in OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Is it possible to use part of a larger image as a marker with OpenLayers?

Like this (in google maps):

```
var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
"img/marker_sprite.png", 
new google.maps.Size(26, 44), 
new google.maps.Point(0, 44)
);
```

Comment: Well you need to start by telling us what library you're using to display OpenStreetMap tiles. The fact that you're displaying OpenStreetMap is largely irrelevant, what matters is the library/toolkit you're using to do it.

Comment: Sry, of course! I forgot it. I am using OpenLayers

Answer (score 1):

The basic recipe for adding a marker to a map in OpenLayers starts with adding a Marker layer to your map, which you can do like this:

```
var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
map.addLayer(markers);
```

Then you will need to add markers to that layer, which goes something like this:

```
var position = new OpenLayers.LonLat(longitude, latitude);
position.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326",
                   map.getProjectionObject());

var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon("img/marker_sprite.png",
                               new OpenLayers.Size(26, 44));

var marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(position, icon);
markers.addMarker(marker);
```

Unfortunately it's not possible, as far as I know, so set the origin for the marker within the image file so you can just use part of the image. Well you can, but only if the part you want is in the corner, which isn't very helpful.

Comment: crow too soon :-(

I found somethink like this for your example:

"... Icon is used as the visual representation of a Marker. Creating such a representation requres up to three parts: An Icon URL, a size, and an offset. The icon URL is a pointer to an image to use as an icon. The size is the size of the image, as an OpenLayers.Size object, and the offset is the position of the top left corner of the image in pixels, relative to the latitude and longitude of the Marker. ..."

Its only the offset =( 
It doesnt positioning the background. The problem is also, that it is a IMG-Tag...

Comment: new OpenLayers.Icon(img,size,pixel)

The third parameter did not position the sprite-graphic in the background. It position the marker on the map relative to the coords.

Comment: Oh so you're saying that you want to extract a piece of a larger image and use that as your marker? No, I don't think OL can do that directly.